# Spring Batch annotation based Job added as a step to XML based job

Tags: spring-batch, spring-batch-tasklet

We have a Spring batch project which is XML based
We need to create a new job and we need to add the job as a nested job to previous XML based job
Is it possible to create the new Job annotation based and add a step to existing XML based job?

I have created a Tasklet Step and tried adding to XML based Job as a Step and am getting.

Cannot convert value of type 'org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep' to required type 'org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.Tasklet' for property 'tasklet': no matching editors or conversion strategy found

Answer (score 0):

A tasklet is not the appropriate type to delegate a step processing to a job, you should use a [JobStep](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.2.x/api/org/springframework/batch/core/step/job/JobStep.html) instead.

The main job can be defined in XML and refer to the "delegate" job (which could be a bean defined in XML or Java config). Here is an example:

```
<batch:job id="mainJob">
    <batch:step id="step">
        <batch:job ref="subjob">
        </batch:job>
    </batch:step>
</batch:job>
```

In this example, `subjob` could be a Spring Batch job defined in XML or Java config.